# SQL query that combine 3 tables with a string like output

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to to write a query that combine 3 different table and present them in a certain way.

- **Table 1:** Employees
- **Table 2:** Departments
- **Table 3:** Cars

Employees table has a joint column for join uses to '**Department**' table (***department_id***) and '**Cars**' table (***emp_id***).

---

I need to write a query that display the following data according to the user details (including the 'department' and 'cars' tables):

1. Employees - **All columns**
2. Department - **Department column**
3. Cars - **All columns but written as a string text with " , " seperating each column in the string**.

---

I got the following query but I don't know how to print the "Cars" table columns as a string:

```
select
  Employees.*, 
  Departments.department, 
  Cars.* 
from Employee
join department on departments.id = employees.department_id 
join Cars on cars.emp_id = employees.id order by employees.id
```

Comment: could you provide version and database name?

Comment: Hello shaki, please provide the DBMS, sample data and desired output.

Comment: Tag your question properly.  Which dbms is this?

Comment: it's postgresql.
The desired output is:
all Employee columns, Department column and a string of all Cars columns separated by a comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you want:

```
select e.*,d.*,concat(c.col1,c.col2,c.col3.... ,',')
from Employees e,Departments d,Cars c
where 
e.department_id=d.department_id 
and d.emp_id=e.emp_id
order by e.emp_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can *see* the results as a record, which is almost the format you want:

```
select e.*, d.department, c 
from Employee e join
     department d
     on d.id = e.department_id join
     Cars c
     on c.emp_id = e.id
order by e.id;
```

Because you want the comma separator, you can get the result as a string using:

```
select e.*, d.department,
       substring(c::text, 2, length(c::text) - 2) as cars
from Employee e join
     department d
     on d.id = e.department_id join
     Cars c
     on c.emp_id = e.id
order by e.id;
```